# Android fragment show/hide is not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

In my activity I have 2 fragments of a same type but different instances and I want to show one and hide the other when different button is pressed.

Here is the code for adding fragments to the activity:

```
_pardisCinemaFragment = NewsListingFragment.newInstance(TAB_CINEMA);
    _shoppingFragment = NewsListingFragment.newInstance(TAB_SHOPPING);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(
            R.anim.enter_from_left,
            R.anim.exit_to_left,
            R.anim.enter_from_left,
            R.anim.exit_to_left);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.add(R.id.news_list_fragment_container, _pardisCinemaFragment);
    transaction.add(R.id.news_list_fragment_container, _shoppingFragment);
    transaction.commit();
```

and here's the onclick event:

```
public void onTabClick(View view) {


    String tag = view.getTag().toString();
    Fragment fragmentToShow = null;
    Fragment fragmentToHide = null;
    if(tag.equals(TAB_CINEMA) && !currentTab.equals(TAB_CINEMA)) {
        currentTab = TAB_CINEMA;
        fragmentToShow = _pardisCinemaFragment;
        fragmentToHide = _shoppingFragment;

    }
    else if(tag.equals(TAB_SHOPPING) && !currentTab.equals(TAB_SHOPPING)) {
        currentTab = TAB_SHOPPING;
        fragmentToShow = _shoppingFragment;
        fragmentToHide = _pardisCinemaFragment;
    }
    if(fragmentToHide != null && fragmentToShow != null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
          .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
          .hide(fragmentToHide)
          .show(fragmentToShow)
          .commit();
    }
}
```

but nothing happens and it doesn't hide then show the fragments. is it because of the way they are added? 
I understand that if one of the fragments are supposed to be hidden at first, there is no need to add it until the user presses the button but since some data has to be populated into the fragment view from phone's database I want it to be happening at the back while it's not visible.

Comment: Why don't you use `replace()` insetad of `show()` and `hide()`?

Comment: @Amy I thought of that but isn't replacing the fragment removes it and then after I replace it back it will go through the complete lifecycle again? which basically means it will generate the view again. right?

Comment: Have you already debugged your app? Set breakpoints when you get your tag, when you set your fragments and maybe you can see what is wrong. Maybe your tag on your view isn't set right and doesn't equal any of your checked tags..?

Comment: When the Fragments are same why not use only one fragment ? very first time add and the later time replace ?

Comment: @Haroon they are showing a same listing but different content is loaded inside the list. Isn't replacing cause the fragment to be added to the activity and goes through the complete fragment life cycle again?

Comment: If you find it by TAG and then apply transaction , i think you save some . you can pass the data set to get Instance and extract it via bundle , so when you need the dynamic data to inflate into fragment View you are good to go , first time add , the fragment and later you can find em using TAG and preform transaction.

Comment: Just replace the list contents. No need of `show`/`hide`. If you are using adapter change the adapter contents and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.